# Docker container has different behaviour on server than local machine - uwsgi and nginx

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose, uwsgi

My docker container seems to deploy correctly when running it from my MacOS machine, but fails to import the app module when running from my remote Ubuntu 18.04 server. It is a flask app that uses uwsgi and nginx as a web server. Exact error is

> ImportError: No module named 'app'

I have tried different configurations of the various files below, without any success.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.5

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        libatlas-base-dev gfortran nginx supervisor

RUN pip3 install uwsgi

COPY requirements.txt /project/requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install -r /project/requirements.txt

RUN useradd --no-create-home nginx

RUN rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
RUN rm -r /root/.cache

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
COPY flask-site-nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
COPY uwsgi.ini /etc/uwsgi/
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/

COPY /app /project

WORKDIR /project

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

Supervisord:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:uwsgi]
command=/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/uwsgi.ini --die-on-term
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0

[program:nginx]
command=/usr/sbin/nginx
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

uwsgi:

```
[uwsgi]
module = app.wsgi
callable = app

uid = nginx
gid = nginx

socket = /tmp/uwsgi.sock
chown-socket = nginx:nginx
chmod-socket = 664

cheaper = 1
processes = %(%k + 1)
```

Really appreciate any input or advice - thanks in advance!

Comment: And have you tried running the container with `docker run -ti --entrypoint /bin/bash` and poking around manually with `cd` & `ls` yet? Also `COPY /app /project` looks dubious. That `COPY` might have failed if you do not have `/app` available as part of your Docker build context.

Comment: The comment above seems worth a look. Please let us know what you find.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me! I was able to solve the issue - I needed it to make a new folder called app inside that container, then copy the files into that.

Answer (score 0):

Possible explanation:

On OS X, the default is a case-insensitive file system.

On Ubuntu, you almost certainly have a case-sensitive file system.

Do you use a file called `Supervisord` which is the same as `supervisord` on a case-insensitive file system but not on a case-sensitive one?

Comment: Unfortunately, the file names are the same (lowercase) on both systems. Also, the docker image is still the same so it should theoretically not matter, or am I incorrect?

Comment: I was thinking there might be inconsistency in your use of case for file or directory names. If they are consistent, then my explanation is not the cause of the issue.